# Issue creating angular project with angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular

I am using Windows 10, I never had any issue using [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/)
to create and run angular project, today i noticed i was still able to run old ones using `ng serve` but when i tried to create new ones with `ng new *name*` I had these warnings at the end of the creation logs:

```
npm WARN rollback Rolling back minimist@1.2.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Talon\Desktop\angular\angular-essentials-two\routing\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules'
npm WARN @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.51 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.28 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.16 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.28 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

If I then try to go to the project and run `ng serve` I have

```
module.js:540
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Talon\Desktop\angular\angular-essentials-two\routing\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\tree\virtual.js:10:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

I googled around and found this [fix](https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/256), but if I try to run `npm install -g @angular-devkit/core` I have

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular-devkit/core@0.0.28
updated 1 package in 9.351s
```

And if I `ng serve` I have the same **Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'** error.

I don't know if it's a coincidence but before the latest Windows 10 update i had a couple of days ago everything was working fine. 
My current angular cli version is `1.6.3`.

Comment: Try `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/core`, literally just ran into this error for the first time just now and that's what fixed it for me... maybe they updated something last night?

Comment: That fixed it. It threw the same `skipping optional depedency` messages at the end but if I run it, it works properly.

Comment: Don't worry about the fsevents dependency, it's for iOS only I believe (both windows and linux pop this soft _optional_ dependency warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/core` will solve this issue